# Как запустить metro-приложение без Visual Studio

Tags: c#, metro-framework

Создал тестовое приложение - в Visual Studio все отлично работает. Нажимаю компилировать и все запускается. Захотелось мне попробовать программу на другом компе - и облом! `exe` файл не запускается. Пишет

```
Это приложение может работать только в контексте контейнера приложения
```

Как собрать приложение в один единый файл, ну или как вообще запускаются `metro` приложения?*

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Вы и на текущем компьютере просто так exe-файл не запустите - только в отладке под Visual Studio.

[Создайте пакет](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/apps/hh464929.aspx) для Windows Store либо для разработки, после чего установите его через Windows Store либо через запуск сгенерированного при построении пакета установочного PowerShell-скрипта.

Comment: елы-палы как все сложно)Неужели нет кнопки создать пакет)))?

Comment: @Radzhab, в студии - [есть конечно](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/patricka/archive/2012/11/05/how-do-i-deploy-a-windows-8-app-to-another-device-for-testing.aspx) - пункт меню Store/Create Package.